# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему слипаются карточки товара? Что нужно сделать?

Tags: html, отступы

[image: проблема]

```html
 <html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="https://xn--80aaph2avkn4e.xn--p1ai/wa-data/public/shop/products/42/33/63342/images/138892/138892.750x0.jpg" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Мёртвые души"</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Роман-поэма Гоголя, написанная в 1842 году.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="https://fkniga.ru/media/product/04/040404/KA-00044753.jpg" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Записки сумасшедшего"</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Повесть Гоголя, написанная им в 1834 году.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://book24.kz/upload/iblock/c49/c49cb0f25ad67b6bb491664638dd38cb.jpg" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Ревизор"</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Комедия Гоголя, написанная им в 1835 году.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/11396163/2a0000018b50fa6ed56e72475cdcefb9a053/600x800">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Г.Д.Мопассан "Жизнь"</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Роман французского писателя Мопассана, написанный в 1883 году.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/4557391/img_id7022216304970178900.jpeg/600x800">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">И.А.Бунин "Митина любовь"</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Повесть Бунина, написанная в 1924 году.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<div class="col">
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/5391380/img_id6669193453551120191.jpeg/600x800" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Ф.М.Достоевский "Белые ночи"</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Повесть Достоевского, написанная в 1848 году.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div></form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Почемум бы вам не выучить CSS и не сверстать самому, вместо того, чтобы использовать бутстрап?

Comment: В учебном заведении говорят с ним работать

Comment: Для класса `card` добавьте, допустим `margin-bottom` внешний отступ снизу

Comment: В bs есть специальные настройки отступов cетки https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

Comment: @OliverPatterson может быть человек именно bootstrap учит) Да и очень много где сейчас именно он используется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это можно реализовать

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://xn--80aaph2avkn4e.xn--p1ai/wa-data/public/shop/products/42/33/63342/images/138892/138892.750x0.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Мёртвые души"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Роман-поэма Гоголя, написанная в 1842 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://fkniga.ru/media/product/04/040404/KA-00044753.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Записки сумасшедшего"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Повесть Гоголя, написанная им в 1834 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://book24.kz/upload/iblock/c49/c49cb0f25ad67b6bb491664638dd38cb.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Ревизор"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Комедия Гоголя, написанная им в 1835 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/11396163/2a0000018b50fa6ed56e72475cdcefb9a053/600x800" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Г.Д.Мопассан "Жизнь"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Роман французского писателя Мопассана, написанный в 1883 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/4557391/img_id7022216304970178900.jpeg/600x800" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">И.А.Бунин "Митина любовь"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Повесть Бунина, написанная в 1924 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/5391380/img_id6669193453551120191.jpeg/600x800" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Ф.М.Достоевский "Белые ночи"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Повесть Достоевского, написанная в 1848 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

В данном примере высота карточек варьируется в зависимости от содержимого.
Если Вам нужна одинаковая высота карточек, то добавьте класс  h-100  к классу card:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://xn--80aaph2avkn4e.xn--p1ai/wa-data/public/shop/products/42/33/63342/images/138892/138892.750x0.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Мёртвые души"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Роман-поэма Гоголя, написанная в 1842 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://fkniga.ru/media/product/04/040404/KA-00044753.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Записки сумасшедшего"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Повесть Гоголя, написанная им в 1834 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://book24.kz/upload/iblock/c49/c49cb0f25ad67b6bb491664638dd38cb.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Н.В.Гоголь "Ревизор"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Комедия Гоголя, написанная им в 1835 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/11396163/2a0000018b50fa6ed56e72475cdcefb9a053/600x800" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Г.Д.Мопассан "Жизнь"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Роман французского писателя Мопассана, написанный в 1883 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/4557391/img_id7022216304970178900.jpeg/600x800" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">И.А.Бунин "Митина любовь"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Повесть Бунина, написанная в 1924 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/5391380/img_id6669193453551120191.jpeg/600x800" class="card-img-top" alt="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Ф.М.Достоевский "Белые ночи"</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Повесть Достоевского, написанная в 1848 году.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Читать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```